# Can we implement multiple QtRO interfaces in the same object?

Tags: c++, qt, moc

It's all in the question.

I am wondering if we can implement multiple QtRO (Qt remote objects) interfaces in the same object. And then in the client side acquire a replica of the part we need of the server object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones who wondered, we can't inherit multiple interfaces because of the QObject inheritance limitation, but we can remote multiple object with same host node. Then in the client side you acquire the wanted interface for the node.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm imagining this is done via multiple `.rep` interfaces, would that be feasible?